# Objective C: Tabbar Controller: How do I select the tab and pop the set of views to root?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, rootview

In my notification did receive method, I want the app to go to the selected tab and display the root view controller of the tab.

I tried the following implementation but the selected tab did not display the root view controller. How can I make this work?

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    self.tabController.selectedIndex = 2; 

    //Pop View Controller to root
   [self.tabController.selectedViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];     
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if everything is set up or connected correctly, i.e. tabController is non-nil? Check with the debugger tabController, tabController.selectedViewController and tabCongtroller.selectedViewController.navigationController - both for non-nil and if they point to the instance you think they should.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    self.tabController.selectedIndex = 2; 

    //Pop View Controller to root
   [self.tabController.selectedViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];     
}
```